# HTTP RFC Multiple headers with same name and different style

Tags: http, http-headers, feign, rfc, openfeign

In my team, we are wondering if ***is compliant with HTTP to have multiple response headers with the same name but different writing styles***. For example, we have a provider whose responses include headers `'set-cookie' and 'Set-Cookie'`.

We use Feign to send requests and manage responses. The feign.Client.Default is case insensitive when managing these headers, so we end up losing some cookies.

We have started using feign-HC5 as a workaround to solve this issue but we are wondering if this scenario is correct or not.

We know is possible to use the same name/key multiple times, but is posible with different style too?